# Python3 detecting manual termination

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, exit

Is it possible to detect if user quit the terminal/command line by pressing X button and take actions before that for example some cleanup or asking user whether he wants to save data?

Comment: What terminal application on what operating system is the user using?  I doubt they all implement the 'X' button the same way.

Comment: I would like to make a cross-platform application using something like platform.system() so Terminal on Linux and CMD on Windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - How to detect when user closes a console application via “X” button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334614/python-how-to-detect-when-user-closes-a-console-application-via-x-button), [how to detect program exited in python on windows and do something on exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901493/how-to-detect-program-exited-in-python-on-windows-and-do-something-on-exit)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - How to detect when user closes a console application via "X" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334614/python-how-to-detect-when-user-closes-a-console-application-via-x-button)