# How do I handle Windows Terminal Closing event in Python?

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, terminal, callback

I run a .py script with Windows Terminal using 'py' command. Is there any callback function that I can add to that .py script to handle the event of closing the Terminal Windows unexpectedly? (hit the 'X' button for example)

Comment: Why would you need a callback for terminal closing?

Comment: Also, does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334614/python-how-to-detect-when-user-closes-a-console-application-via-x-button) answer your question?

Comment: @PyxlDavon my program is a gateway for other embedded devices, I just want to handle all unexpected situations so that I can publish a gateway status signal to my broker.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
import time

def on_exit(sig, func=None):
print("exit handler")
time.sleep(10)  # so you can see the message before program exits
```

-Windows:

if you install pywin32 package, you can :

```
import win32api
win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(on_exit, True)
```

If you are on Windows, opt for win32api.

-Un*x:

Or, using python internal "signal" library, if you are using under *nix system:

```
import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, on_exit)
```